# Как осуществить поиск по карте Google Map?

Tags: android

Как осуществить поиск по карте Google Map. Найти надо музеи на карте. 
Пробую через

```
geocoder.getFromLocationName(region+","+музей, 100);
```

Но ничего не выходит, вернее отображаются те музеи, в которых в адресе прописано слово "Музей"

```
public void Onfind(View w) throws IOException {
    String region="";
    EditText myText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editSearch);
    region=myText.getText().toString();

    Geocoder geocoder=new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
    List<Address> locations=geocoder.getFromLocationName(region, 100);
    for (int i=0; i<locations.size(); i++) {
        Address loc=locations.get(i);

        LatLng TempFind =
                new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(),loc.getLongitude());

        //...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Так оно так и должно быть отображаться по слову, поиск. все таки это не полноценный поиск, что бы все результаты показывать. Может по категориям обрабатывает. Либо свою делать с забивкой адресов.